# While rebuilding sitecore index getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: solr, azure, sitecore-api

We have deployed `Sitecore` instance in `Azure`.When we try to rebuild `master index` getting below exception. We are using `Sitecore 9.0.1` version.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_master_index_rebuild\data\index\segments_e7
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:193)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
    at java.nio.file.Files.size(Files.java:2332)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:243)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.fileLength(NRTCachingDirectory.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler.getFileLength(LukeRequestHandler.java:615)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler.getIndexInfo(LukeRequestHandler.java:588)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.getCoreStatus(CoreAdminOperation.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.StatusOp.execute(StatusOp.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:384)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:748)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:729)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:510)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Solr will throw that exception at startup if the index directory exists but is empty. However, if you delete the directory, Solr will create it and the empty segments files at startup.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal , i have deleted entire index and rebuild still getting same exception

Comment: @GauravAgarwal, we are getting this exception at the end

Comment: @Reddy Did you check this Question related to you. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/solr-intermittently-failing-with-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception Where Marek suggested that this is still in discussion. And he also updated few things for this.