# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_web_index_sec\data\index\_2yh.si

Tags: solr

We were using `Sitecore 10.2` and `Solr 8.8.2`. We could see this error again and again. What is fix for this error?

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_web_index_sec\data\index\_2yh.si
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/solr-intermittently-failing-with-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception

Answer (score 0):

Is it a docker setup? If yes then there is a workaround: change isolation level from process to hyperv for the solr service (at minimum)

So either update your `.env` file:

```
ISOLATION=hyperv
```

Alternatively set the `solr` service to run in `hyperv` in the `docker-compose.yml` or `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

```
solr:
    isolation: hyperv
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/solr:8.4.0-${SITECORE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8984:8983"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\solr-data
        target: c:\data
    environment:
      SOLR_MODE: solrcloud
```

Follow the thread - https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/issues/182